# Conditionally set checked to checkbox in React Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap, conditional-rendering

I have an Checkbox input in React Bootstrap.
if my Variable `isTrue=true`  I want to set checked to my input.

I'm adding `checked ={isTrue ? true : false}` to the input, but after I do this, I'm unable to uncheck it. (I have this input in a loop)

```
<input type='checkbox' checked ={isTrue ? true : false}  />
```

When I do this:

```
<input type="checkbox" {checked ? 'checked' : ''} name="example" />
```

I get error: "Spread types may only be created from object types.ts(2698)"

How can I conditionally set `checked` to a checkbox input?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to `useEffect` that will run when `isTrue` changes (from false to true). So it will change the value of the state variable that is bind to a checkbox:

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

function App() {
  const [isTrue, setIsTrue] = useState(false);
  const [checkBoxValue, setCheckBoxValue] = useState(false);

  const onButtonClick = () => {
    setIsTrue((curr) => !curr);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isTrue) return;
    setCheckBoxValue(true);
  }, [isTrue]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>IsTrue: {isTrue.toString()}</p>
      <p>CheckBox value: {checkBoxValue.toString()}</p>
      <button type="button" onClick={onButtonClick}>
        Toggle isTrue
      </button>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        onChange={() => setCheckBoxValue((curr) => !curr)}
        checked={checkBoxValue}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <App />
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this and it worked.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="example"  {...(isTrue  && { checked: true })} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can

```
<input type='checkbox' checked ={isTrue} onClick={handleChange}  />
```

And create your function that handles the onClick and change the isTrue accordingly